# What is the best way to specify a simple configuation file HTML or javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple list of configuration items I want to create in a file. It will be list of `name`s and then an `enabled` boolean attribute associated with that name:

```
name = "name 1" enable = "true"
name = "name 2" enable = "false"
```

What is the best way to specify this so I can load it at start up as a configuation file? HTML or JavaScript?

Are there pro/cons to each approach?

If anybody has some examples of each approach that would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean.  How are you going to *use* this "configuration file"?

Comment: This is a prime use case for a JSON object, but without some context it's hard to say.

Comment: a lot of configs are in XML, but once again impossible to answer

Comment: At startup I want to be able to access this list from javascript when the app is first starting. Based upon the configuration file I do certain things to the app at startup.

Comment: than use JSON object

Comment: I will give that a shot. thanks. Just wanted to make sure that was the best option.

Comment: If I just have a JDOM object is this a HTML or javascript file {"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a JSON object.

```
{
    "name 1":"true",
    "name 2":"false"
}
```

If you're using JavaScript, then once you read the file / get the data from somewhere, you can parse it and access the properties:

```
var config = JSON.parse(fileData);
console.log(config["name 1"]); //"true"
```

You can't really load files client-side in JavaScript, so your options are limited unless you serve the JSON configuration file from your server (and get it via a GET request). A hacky alternative is to write a simple JavaScript object as a config, and include that file as a `<script>` tag. If you want to get really fancy, you can have a function add this script tag for you, pass it a name to load the configuration into, and then have a callback to access the object once the script loads.

For example:

### config.js

```
window[configName()] = {
  key1:"value1",
  key2:"value2"
}
```

### main.js

```
/* Gets the name of the config object from the script src */
var configName = function() {
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for(var i=0; i<scripts.length; i++){
      if (scripts[i].getAttribute.length !== undefined && scripts[i].getAttribute('src').indexOf('#isConfig') > -1){
        var spl = scripts[i].getAttribute('src', 2).split('?');
        return spl.length === 2 ? spl[1].substr(0, spl[1].indexOf('#')) : 'config';
      }
    }
};

/* Loads the config script */
var loadConfig = function(src, callback) {
  var d = document, tag = 'script',
      element = d.createElement(tag),
      script = d.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0];
  element.src = src + '#isConfig';
  if (callback) { element.addEventListener('load', function (e) { callback(null, e); }, false); }
  script.parentNode.insertBefore(element, script);
}

/* Load the config and display on page */
loadConfig('config.js?configObj', function() {
    document.getElementById('configDiv').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(configObj);
});
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/gGilGojZqrHosNYDx36V?p=preview

Comment: How do I reference the jsonData var from another javascript file?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way to load data with html, the closest you could do is hard code it and then grab the data with javascript after. This approach would be a little cumbersome.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/arf4v1nr/

```
<input type="hidden" value="name1" data-enabled="true"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="name2" data-enabled="true"></input>
<script>
  var jsonData=[];
  $('input').each(function(index,obj) {
    jsonData.push({name:$(obj).val(), enabled:$(obj).data('enabled')})
  })
</script>
```

The better way would just be to go ahead and put the data into your `jsonData` var right off the get go

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/1gxwdsd6/

**File:** jsonData.js

```
var jsonData[{
 name:"name 1",
 enable: "true"
},{ 
 name: "name 2",
 enable: "false"
}]
```

**"How do I reference the jsonData var from another javascript file"**

**HTML**

```
<script src="./jsonData.js"></script>
<script>
  console.log(jsonData);
</script>
```

Comment: How do I reference the jsonData var from another javascript file?

Comment: see appended edit above